# Помогите расставить запятые

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно расставить запятые:
"Мастер отлипает от тёплого печного бока, и, повернувшись, пристально смотрит в спину ученика, до сих пор стоящего, с руками, погружёнными в кадку".
P. S. Особенно беспокоит запятая между "с руками" и "погружёнными".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Мастер отлипает от тёплого печного бока, и, повернувшись, пристально
>   смотрит в спину ученика, до сих пор стоящего, с руками, погруженными в
>   кадку.

Запятая перед "и" не нужна  — этот союз соединяет однородные сказуемые: *мастер  **отлипает** и **смотрит**...*

> Особенно беспокоит запятая между "с руками" и "погруженными".

Лучше, по-моему, немного изменить порядок слов:

*Мастер отлипает от тёплого печного бока и, повернувшись, пристально смотрит в спину ученика, до сих пор стоящего с погруженными в кадку руками.*

Comment: Пожалуй, так и сделаю. Ни экспрессия, ни тектоника от этого не меняются.

Comment: Как мне нравятся эти "экспрессия и тектоника"... Нет, пардон, а то наговорю лишнего :)

Comment: А мы, университетов не кончали. :) Называем, как другие называют. Слова "Тектоника текста" употребляет очень мною уважаемый историк Юрий Алексеевич Соколов. Причём, "вкусно" так употребляет! Ну, и логике это выражение не противоречит никак. На самом деле, текст должен иметь законченную, цельную структуру.

Answer (score 1):

***Мастер отлипает от тёплого печного бока и, повернувшись, пристально смотрит в спину ученика, до сих пор стоящего с погруженными в кадку руками.*** Может, лучше так?

Перед И запятую не ставьте, союз И соединяет однородные сказуемые.

В вашем примере причастный оборот *погружёнными в кадку* стоит после определяемого слова *руками*, поэтому запятая нужна. (Мастер отлипает от тёплого печного бока и, повернувшись, пристально смотрит в спину ученика, до сих пор стоящего с руками, погруженными в кадку).

Comment: "Мастер отлипает от тёплого печного бока и, повернувшись, пристально смотрит в спину ученика, до сих пор стоящего с руками, погруженными в кадку" - именно таков и был первоначальный вариант. Но, когда начинаешь вчитываться, мозга заходит за мозгу. :) Тем не менее, вариант " ...пристально смотрит в спину ученика, до сих пор стоящего с погруженными в кадку руками: "  мне подходит.

Comment: В первоначальном варианте были две лишние запятые, я их убрала, поэтому и написала предложение ещё раз в скобках.

Comment: По всей видимости, мне придётся предложение за предложением выкладывать здесь, на сайте. А-то я уже стал сомневаться в каждой запятой! Очень жаль, что на этом ресурсе нельзя говорить "Спасибо!" в комментариях. Поэтому, я не говорю "Спасибо!" и ещё раз не говорю "Спасибо!" всем вам за помощь. Да простят меня модераторы!

Answer (score 0):

> > P.S. Особенно беспокоит запятая между "с руками" и "погруженными"

А зря. Должна беспокоить запятая между "бока" и "и". Ее не нужно. Смотрите:

*Мастер отлипает от тёплого печного бока и пристально смотрит...* Запятой нет.

А еще не нужна между "стоящего" и "с руками". Он стоит с руками, погруженными в кадку! Или он стоит, а руки у него погружены в кадку?! ))

Comment: Запятая перед "И" - это уже от полнейшего бессилия. :) Никак фраза не строилась.

Answer (score 0):

Можно оставить начальный вариант, убрав две запятые:

Мастер отлипает от тёплого печного бока и, повернувшись, пристально смотрит в спину ученика, до сих пор стоящего с руками, погруженными в кадку.

Рассмотрим предложение: Ученик стоял с руками, погруженными в кадку. Здесь падежная форма "с руками" относится к сказуемому и не обособляется. Сравнить: Я стоял у кромки озера с опущенным ружьём.

Comment: Всё-таки, вариант уважаемого slava1947 мне понравился больше, чем мой собственный. Фраза как бы выровнялась! Водится за мной такой грешок - витиеватость. Которая всё портит.

Comment: В данном случае Вы правы: обособление причастного оборота осложняет структуру предложения и ухудшает целостность восприятия всего текста. В то же время теоретически применяться могут обе грамматические формы, так что автор может выбрать подходящий ему вариант.